Javascript text compression
I have tried "pako" and lz-string" Both. I need text compression of 25% or lower.
I am trying to convert 1000 Characters to 222 or less chars after compression.
pako do a good job than lz string. Lz string reduced 1k chars to max 800 chars, while pako reduced 1k chars to 550 chars. its good enough but not much to go below 222.
As memos of blockchain transactions usually dont allow more than 200-230 chars in memo. I need to send user texts on Memo to on-chain. But user text inputs are usually more than 1k, lets say they are max 1k we can put limit to 1k, we need a way to reduce text chars to 222 or less.
In short i need some js compression method (to run in browser in next js app) that can compress 1000 text characters (not words) to mere 222 or less.
Some important notes:
user will input text, then we will compress it to 222 or les chars
This will be gone permanatly on-chain.
Then i need to show it decompressed in my app.
means Almost all work is done in user browser, no apis should be here, only js in-broswer libraries etc or something.
I already tried different encoding compression methods of pako and lz-string, but both dont seem to go under 500 chars for 1000 chars input

You're not saying what is in your 1000-character string, but it is very unlikely to get that much compression on a large amount of normal text, and certainly not on a string that short. Your 1000-character string would need to have some special characteristics to be compressible by that much.

Yeah, thats exactly my problem, its on-chain messaging app. So user can input any thing that can be typed. i need something that can convert that thing into mere 222 chars.
Its possible or not, if we dont really have patterns.

Compression depends on there being repeated patterns. 25% compression requires that the average length of the patterns is at least 4 characters. LZ compression is adaptive, it learns the patterns as it goes along, but it takes a while for it to get up to that length.

So in short there is no way we can compress human written chat msgs to less than 222 chars. atleast not in js. Btw thanks for help atleast i know it now.

Not in anything.
